# How to properly handle saving redux state before making an API call in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

So I think I understand the flow correctly but would like to get some feedback.

I'm building a React Native app that has a multi page form the user fills out and submits. Upon pressing the submit button I want to save the form data from this last page to my Redux state before making my API call with all of that form data.

Currently this is the flow that I have setup:

1. RN Component Button Press calls SetState to display a dialog and block UI.
2. Dispatch action to update Redux with form data.
3. State updates and calls ComponentWillReceiveProps with newly saved form data.
4. Dispatch action to initiate API call.
5. Handle and save response to Redux.
6. State updates and calls ComponentWillReceiveProps again with API response.
7. If error, show error message dialog, if success then navigate to initial screen and display success message.

I have this working as is but am wondering if this is proper flow of handling this or is there a better preferred solution / pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max has a good flow, another common way to do it is to be always storing all the form values in state whenever the user is even typing them in (in each individual input field). Then the state is at any time ready to to be used even if incomplete. The flow goes as follows:

User types in any field -> Action Creator for that field -> Action -> Reducer saves to store (the button reducer could trigger the api dispatch you're looking for asynchronously with redux thunk) -> state available at any time through mapStateToProps.

Comment: Hmm, I think this might be what I'm looking for, and a little cleaner in the submission flow. I'm guessing actions get dispatched in onChangeText functions for each input field?

Comment: Exactly! You make a helper method for each input and then call them inside the onChangeText for each one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable way to do it, and common among redux users.

For every request, I like to have a threefold group of actions. Something like a `REQUEST` which will reduce the redux store with any state changes I need, a `REQUEST_SUCCESS` which will then update the store with the data from the server, and a `REQUEST_ERROR` which will do the same if there is an error.

Comment: I actually do use these exact actions for my requests. The thing that has me questioning my flow is multiple back and forth between my state and component that I have to check just to be sure I call everything in order.

It seems like it's the React way given their lifecycle and how Redux ties in but I'm still fairly new to the React & Redux world.